# SQL Server Restore w/o "Closing Existing Connections"

Tags: sql-server, restore

By default in SSMS (2012/2014) when you choose to restore a database, the "close existing connections" option located in the [image: Options Screen SSMS] 

is by default unchecked, is it possible to restore a database while maintaining a connection to it (i.e. in an Enterprise Edition)? If not, why have this option (besides as a sanity check), if so? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the option is there for you so that you can decide to either:

1. Kick all users out right now and restore immediately; or,
2. let the restore operation wait until it can get exclusive access to the
   database before it begins.

You can't restore and keep connections active, sorry. This is like changing the keg without interrupting someone actively pouring a beer...

Comment: Cheers! I was fairly sure you probably wouldn't want to, but I guess the unchecked option had me curious for some "undocumented" feature. Thanks for the clarification.